# Do I need to reinstall Xubuntu? A lot of libraries are missing

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, 16.04

I just upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 (not xubuntu) to xubuntu 16.04. During the installation, it said that it had failed to restore some applications. That was the only error it gave.

Now whenever I try to run some applications, they fail to load some libraries, which are supposed to be in /lib folder.

Do I need to reinstall it, overwriting the previous installation?

Comment: How did u update ubuntu 14.04 to xubuntu 16.04.?

Comment: I downloaded the live CD (of xubuntu 16.04), burnt it to a USB stick. It told that I could keep my files and all that, but replace ubuntu 14.04 with xubuntu 16.04, and I chose that option.

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get install -f` from a terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fix dependencies:

```
sudo apt check
sudo apt -f install
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

<s>I want to remember that  in 16.04 apt-get is deprecate</s>

Comment: still won't work

Comment: Can you give me more info about the error?